# WooCommerce Custom Product to checkout

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I was trying to create a custom shop page for a project where users can click on a product to view the details in a modal window and select some options on price variations.

What I want to do is to send the product details to checkout page upon chosen by the user.

Is it possible to do ? If so , how ?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I think you'll find in this post what you are looking for: [Woocommerce single product show in modal…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206492/woocommerce-single-product-show-in-modal-bootstrap) and this additional plugin: [WooCommerce LightBox](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-lightbox/).

Comment: I used woocommerce lightbox what doesn't show up woocommerce extra product options (Plugin) .

Comment: You need first to buy [**WooCommerce Quick View**](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-quick-view/) plugin, because **woocommerce lightbox** plugin doesn't work without it. Have you read  [Woocommerce single product show in modal…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206492/woocommerce-single-product-show-in-modal-bootstrap)? And if you go to the wordpress page of **woocommerce lightbox** plugin, you will see that is a complementary plugin.

Comment: Man you did the great thing for me ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38263/discussion-between-loictheaztec-and-md-atiqur-rahman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to buy *WooCommerce Quick View* plugin, because *woocommerce lightbox* plugin doesn't work without it.

Please read  this: [Woocommerce single product show in modal…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206492/woocommerce-single-product-show-in-modal-bootstrap)

And if you go to the wordpress page of **woocommerce lightbox** plugin, you will see that is a complementary plugin.